# How to execute emacs commands in background

Tags: magit, tramp

When executing some time consuming commands like `magit-status` or using `scp` to transfer files, then Emacs freezes and waits for return. Is there any way I can tell Emacs to run those commands in the background?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no silver bullet.

Magit, and I am sure Tramp, do run some child processes like `git` and `scp` asynchronously in some cases and in other cases they do not. The author has to decide on a case-by-case basis if it makes sense for a process to be run asynchronously and whether it is worth to deal with the additional complexity that comes with doing so.

Generally speaking if a child process is called for a side-effect, e.g. "push my changes to a remote", then things can be done asynchronously. But something like "give me a list of changes" cannot be done asynchronously because you wouldn't be satisfied with a result that boils down to "let me get back to you on that one". You want to see the up-to-date diff now.

In the case of `magit-status`, there is little that can be done asynchronously because its purpose is to show the current status of the repository now. Some things can be done to speed up things anyway and Magit already does some of them and others are in planning. E.g. its possible to cache information so that it does not have to be recalculated over and over again, information that isn't actually required yet because it would be hidden anyway can be calculated only when the respective section is actually expanded, and Magit could be taught that certain commands only require certain parts to be updated (it already knows about commands that don't need any updates at all, most of them at least).

That all requires work and planning and there is no switch in Emacs that magically makes all packages smarter.

The Magit manual has a node about [performance](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Performance.html). There are some tricks in there that might help in your case and you might also learn a thing or two about why some issues exist.